# CKEditor: getting source DOM element of editor?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am wondering: when having reference to the editor object, how can I get the actual underlying source DOM element of that editor - eg. the textarea?

Something like `editor.element`? (doesn't work)

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

There are couple of elements that you may be interested in:

- [`editor.element`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-property-element) - the original element on which editor was initialized. This can be a `textarea` in case of framed editor, editable element with `contenteditable` attribute in case of inline editor or container into which editor was appended (when using `CKEDITOR.appendTo`).
- [`editor.container`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-property-container) - the main CKEditor UI container.
- [`editor.editable()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-editable) - this is a method which returns current [`CKEDITOR.editable`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editable) instance. Editable inherits from element and it is the element in which contents of the editor is placed, so e.g. in case of inline editor editable equals to `editor.element` (although `===` won't work, because it's not the same instance) and in case of framed editor editable is the `body` element inside the `iframe`.

Now, CKEditor has its own DOM manipulation library (it's not using jQuery, because it was created long before it). And all these properties and methods return instances of [`CKEDITOR.dom.element`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.element) which is very different from jQuery.

However, you can unwrap CKEditor's element and wrap it in jQuery:

```
jQuery( editor.editable().$ ).css( 'color', 'red' );

// Or:

jQuery( editor.element.$ ).hide();
```

Comment: Sorry to dig this up, but, in my plugin `init()` function, `editor.container` is undefined, `editor.editable()` returns undefined... what can I do to get the actual container?  I want a clean way to grab the toolbar and position it `fixed` when the page scrolls past it (using the auto-grow plugin).

Comment: Call editor.editable() after ckeditor is loaded. Use the event on('loaded', function...)